# How can I recover from a failed drive in a BTRFS RAID1 array: devid uuid .... missing

Tags: btrfs, raid

I have a BTRFS disk from a two-disk raid1 array. When I try to mount the drive, I get

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
BTRFS info (device sda2): using crc32c (crc32c-intel) checksum algorithm
BTRFS info (device sda2): using free space tree
BTRFS error (device sda2): devid 1 uuid c57fb489-31dc-4867-86b5-cec766f6f937 is missing
BTRFS error (device sda2): failed to read the system array: -2
BTRFS error (device sda2): open_ctree failed
BTRFS: device fsid 7d78ed4b-e4aa-4270-853d-6489ea4d6c54 devid 2 transid 358993 /dev/sda2 scanned by mount (54712)
```

The other drive has failed. How can I mount this drive?

Answer (score 0):

Use the mount option `degraded`.